# Python decorating / importing .... how can I eliminate the __init__.py in this solution?

Tags: python-3.x, import, python-decorators

Python 3.8

So I have two versions of my software - a standard edition and a pro edition.

I want to be able to have precisely the same code base, but simply by dropping in some additional files, pro features are enabled.

I am doing this by decorating/wrapping the standard version Python functions, so the pro edition functions are seamlessly extending the behaviour of the standard functions.

I've made a simple example of this below.

The fooble.py imports "do_something" from the foo module.

The **init**.py tries to import the pro functions from test_decorate_pro.py.  If it succeeds in the import, then it wraps the standard edition function "do_something" with the pro edition function of the same name "do_something".

All this works.

The problem is that I wanted to NOT have two **init**.py files.  This solution only works if the standard edition has its own **init**.py that must be overwritten by the new **init**.py  -

standard edition **init**.py

```
import sys
from .test_decorate import do_something
```

**So my question is.... is there a solution for this in which I can eliminate the standard edition **init**.py somehow**?  I want my pro features to be added by simply dropping in additional files.  I don't want to be overwriting anything in the standard edition - I'd like the pro edition to add its features in to the codebase simply by adding, with no overwriting or deleting.  And I want there to be no pro edition related code at all in the standard edition codebase, so I don't want to just use the pro edition **init**.py  Hopefully that makes sense.

the directory structure:

```
fooble.py
foo/__init__.py
foo/test_decorate.py
foo/test_decorate_pro.py
```

fooble.py:

```
from foo import do_something

do_something('xxx')
```

foo/**init**.py

```
import sys
from .test_decorate import do_something
try:
    import foo.test_decorate_pro
except ImportError as e:
    pass

if 'foo.test_decorate_pro' in sys.modules:
    do_something = foo.test_decorate_pro.do_something(do_something)
```

foo/test_decorate.py

```
def do_something(name):
   print(f"STANDARD do something {name}")
```

foo/test_decorate_pro.py

```
import wrapt

@wrapt.decorator
def do_something(wrapped, instance, args, kwargs):
   print(f"PRO do something args[0]", args, kwargs)
   return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Isn't the point of the conditional logic in your pro-edition `__init__.py` file that it can work in either edition? So ship it with the standard edition and don't include it in the pro-edition.

Comment: @Blckknght ideally I'd like the standard edition to have zero code that references the pro edition at all. As it stands .... my choices are either to have alot of pro edition code in the standard edition __inint__.py OR to overwrite the standard edition __init__.py when pro edition is installed. I guess it doesn't really matter I think I'm just being a perfectionist ... I was going for the goal of a totally "pure" standard edition, with a pro edition that could be dropped on top non destructively.

Comment: @Blckknght alternatively if I could import code into the __init__.py file that would be a great solution, but imported code appears to be executed in the scope of the module it is imported from, which is no use for declaring needed stuff into the scope of __init__.py

Answer (score 1):

The only good way to avoid needing to overwrite the `__init__.py` file is to put the logic that imports the pro  edition (if it's available), in the standard edition. You could simplify this quite a bit if you made the `do_something` function from the pro-edition a drop-in replacement of the function of the same name from the standard edition. You can still implement it with a decorator if that makes sense, you'd just go about it differently (and expose fewer details in `__init__.py`).

Standard edition `test_decorate.py`:

```
def do_something(name):
    print(f"STANDARD do something {name}")
```

Pro edition `test_decorate_pro.py`:

```
from .test_decorate import do_something as do_something_standard

def do_something(name):
    print(f"PRO do something {name}")
    do_something_standard(name)    
    print("done with PRO stuff")
```

Standard edition `__init__.py` file, which should work for the pro edition too:

```
try:
    from .test_decorate_pro import do_something  # try to get the pro version first
except ImportError:
    from .test_decorate import do_something      # fall back to the standard edition
```

Note that I defined the pro-version of the function directly, without using decorator style code. You don't need to make that change, the only important thing is that the `do_stuff` function that you want to expose is the final result of the decoration, not the decorator. There's not really any good reason to use a higher order function like a decorator in this situation, just call the standard version of the function directly, since we can import it from its module in the pro code.

Comment: Solid advice - I certainly like the idea of not using the decorator style syntax if I can avoid it.  I suspect I might just overwrite the standard __init__.py because I'd like the standard edition to have zero connection to the pro edition.  Thanks for your advice and time @blckknght